# JS Class binding class variables

Tags: javascript, class, variables, binding

I have this Javascript class where in construct I initialize some class variable and I bind a click event and I try to get the declared variable if the click method is called, but returns every time undefined

```
class Tabs  {
    constructor() {
        this.tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]')

        let self = this
        if( this.tabLinks.length > 0 ) {
            this.tabContainer = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]')
            this.tabLinks.forEach((el) => {
                el.addEventListener("click", self.setActiveTab, false);
            } )
        }

        return

    }

    setActiveTab(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let currentEl = e.target
        console.log(currentEl)
        console.log(this.tabLinks) // Is undefined

        Tabs.tabLinks.forEach((el) => {
            el.classList.remove("is-active")
        } )


    }
}

export default Tabs
```

what I do wrong in this case?

Comment: Change `self.setActiveTab` to `this.setActiveTab.bind(this)`. You don't need the `self` variable.

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback! Happy new year for you!